# Select data Checkbox - DataTable - Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

How do I do to get the selected data that dataTable? I use this way because it is the "Edit" of a register.

```
    <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="valor" style="width:100%; text-align:center" 
      value="#{beanMensagemXContato.dataModelMsg}"  
      selection="#{beanMensagemXContato.selectedMensagemAssociada}" 
      paginator="true" rows="6" >

       <f:facet name="header">  
           Mensagens  
       </f:facet>   
       <p:column  style="width:5%">
           <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{valor.associada}" >       
                <p:ajax process="@form" event="valueChange"  listener="#   {beanMensagemXContato.adicionarMensagemContato}">                
                <f:param name="messageSelecionada" value="#{beanMensagemXContato.msgAssociada}" />
                </p:ajax>
           </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
       </p:column>   
...
</p:dataTable>
```

I would pick the data by Bean as the event SelectEvent:

```
public void adicionarMensagemContato (SelectEvent event){

    Mensagem mensagem = ((MensagemAssociada) event.getObject()).getMensagem();
    MensagemAssociada mensagemAssociada = (MensagemAssociada) event.getObject();

...

}
```

But I could not take the data with the event ValueChange. I've tried with SelectEvent by tag selectionMode = "multiple", managed to get the data selected at that moment, the data previously selected and read from the database does not appear, use only when the way listed above in xhtml.

Already I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The selection is stored in your bean field:

```
selection="#{beanMensagemXContato.selectedMensagemAssociada}"
```

If the adicionarMensagemContato method is located in the same bean, you can access you selection without a problem:

```
public void adicionarMensagemContato (SelectEvent event){
    doSomething(this.selectedMensagemAssociada);
}
```

Another way is to use f:setPropertyActionListener - it allows you to store element from current row in a bean field (example below shows how to access current element in action invoked by button click):

```
<p:dataTable var="objectFromCurrentRow" ...>
  ...
  <p:column ...>
    <p:button ... action=#{beanMensagemXContato.performAnActionOnCurrentElement} ...>
      <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{objectFromCurrentRow}" target="#{beanMensagemXContato.selectedMensagemAssociada}" />
    </p:button>
    ...
```